# Require directive on template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I am using RequireJS in my Angular app. I would like to `require` my `pill` where it is actualy used.

*pill.js*

```
define([], function() {
    angular.module('app').directive('pill', function() {
        return function(a,b,c) {
            b.html("A pill");
        };
    });
});
```

*incl.html*

```
<div load-script="require(['pill']);"></div>
<div pill>test</div>
```

*main.html*

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.10/comments/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("app", [])
                app.directive('loadScript', function() {
                        return {
                            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                                (new Function(attrs.loadScript))();
                            }
                        };
                    }
                );
        </script>
    <div ng-include="'incl.html'"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This short example should declare a `pill` directive that just transform text from `test` to `A pill` inside `incl.html` file. However, it doesn't work. I guess it is because the `pill` directive is registered after `incl.html` is compiled.

I want avoid declaring directives somwhere globaly for example inside `main.html` because it is not used there. Is this requirement achievable in elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to load `directive` on demand is to create it using `$compileProvider` which you will need to cache during your `app.config` phase.  Also, instead of using `ng-include`, I would suggest you load the `directive` you need when partial view that uses it loads.

To do that, it is actually quite complicated.  I created following library that should help get you started:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/

angularAMD would make it easier for your create a independent file that allow you to configure RequireJS dependency to load the `directive` only on the partials that needs it.